# Passing data array to gnuplot via a pipe in c rather than a file

Tags: c, file, stream, pipe, gnuplot

Right now  I am passing a file to gnuplot via a a pipe in c, something like this:

```
 fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "plot \"data-file.dat\" using 1:2\n");
```

Is there any way that I don't have to write the data to a file and then pass it to gnuplot, so for example somehow pass an array or a stream to gnuplot, so I can skip the writing to a file process and then deleting the file? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can do that. An example of a terminal command that plots two points connected by a line is:

```
echo "plot \"< echo -e '4 5\n 3 2'\" w lp pt 2" | gnuplot
```

If you want to have postscript output you can add the following:

```
echo "set terminal postscript; plot \"< echo -e '4 5\n 3 2'\" w lp pt 2" | gnuplot &> out.ps
```

If you now use system() or popen() (to catch the output stream) the rest should be straightforward.

Edit: There seems to exist some C(++) - Gnuplot interfaces. Check out [this website](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/) which gives a great overview over C, C++, Python and Fortran wrappers. I'm not sure whether they are up to date and work with the latest Gnuplot versions but if not adapting shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not sure though why I would need to catch the output, maybe I am not seeing what you are saying, the graph appears automatically after the plot command.

Comment: Optional in case you plan to do more than just looking at the data. For simple plotting system will be fine.

Comment: sounds good, I'll try your answer, I'll have to convert the array to a huge char array guessing from your answers so I can pass it gnuplot, unless I can somehow directly pass the array (of doubles) itself to gnuplot?

Comment: I updated my answer a little, providing a link that turned up after a quick search.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot understands the filename '-' to mean forthcoming data. So to cut and paste from what I'm working on at the moment:

```
FILE *f = popen("gnuplot", "w");

fprintf(f, "set term png; "
"set out 'beforeafter.png'\n"
"set xlabel 'before'\n"
"set ylabel 'after'\n"
"plot '-'\n");

//Am using Apophenia in my project, so use its print function to print the data
apop_data_print(dataset, .output_pipe=f);

//or use fprintf directly
for (int i=0; i< data_len; i++)
  fprintf(f, "%g %g\n", data_x[i], data_y[i]);

fclose(f);
```